# Solving an equation with Euler's formula using a particular method

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, eulers-number-e

I want to solve the following equation:
$$e^{i\cdot m2\pi}=1$$
Where $i$ is the imaginary unit and $m$ is some constant that I want to determine. 
According to Euler's formula this equation is equal to:
$$e^{i\cdot m2\pi}=\cos(2\pi m)+i\cdot \sin(2\pi m)=1$$
Furthermore, [this link](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/eulers-formula.html) says that the $x$ in $e^{ix}$ can be obtained by:
$$\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\bigg)=x$$
In my case, $x=2\pi m$ which must be $0$ to give $e^{i\cdot m2\pi}=1$. When plotting the following equation with $m$ as the variable:
$$\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{\sin(2\pi m)}{\cos(2\pi m)}\bigg)$$
I get solutions for $0$ when $m=\pm1, 1.5, 2, 2.5,..$
However, [this link](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Quantum_States_of_Atoms_and_Molecules_(Zielinksi_et_al.)/07%3A_Rotational_States/7.03%3A_Solving_the_Rigid_Rotor_Schr%C3%B6dinger_Equation) says at **Equation 7.3.15** that $m$ can only be integers $\pm 1, 2, 3, 4$

Why is my method not working?

Comment: The formula $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\right) = x$ only works for $-\pi/2 < x\leqslant \pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

From your equation 
$$  \cos(2 \pi m) + \mathrm{i} \sin(2\pi m) = 1 + \mathrm{i} 0  $$
we have
$$  \cos(2\pi m) = 1  \quad \text{ and } \quad \sin(2\pi m) = 0  \text{.}  $$
Cosine is only $1$ at integer multiples of $2\pi$, so when $m$ is an integer, and sine is zero at multiples of $\pi$, so when $m$ is a half integer.  Notice that the incorrect set of solutions is one of these and the correct set is their **intersection**.  The intersection of the set of $m$s giving the correct real part and the set of $m$s giving the correct imaginary part is the set of $m$s giving $1$ and is the integers.

Comment: Is it possible to explain what exactly this intersection is? If it's a plot of a function, which function is it that intersects the correct real part and the correct imaginary part?

Comment: @JohnnyGui : Its the intersection of two sets.  The first set is the integers and $m$ in that set makes the real parts match.  The second set is the half integers and $m$ in that set makes the imaginary parts match.  The intersection of these two sets is the integers and $m$ in that set makes both real and imaginary parts match.

Comment: You mean because the combination of the two equations is equal to $$1 + i0 = 1$$ ...this means that it's the integers of $m$ that fullfills this?

Comment: Also, why isn't it chosen that $\cos(2\pi m) = 0$ and $i \sin(2\pi m) = 1$ instead?

Comment: @JohnnyGui : For two complex numbers to be equal, their real parts must be equal and their imaginary parts must be equal.  Equality of the real parts is $\cos(2 \pi m) = 1$.  Equality of the imaginary parts is $\sin(2 \pi m) = 0$.  This follows because cosine and sine both map real numbers to real numbers, so cannot introduce imaginary parts that are not already written multiplied by $\mathrm{i}$.